# How do i choose set of information from a table using information from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'users' and a table called 'posts'. posts table holds id information for users as a foreign key attribute. I want to select every username that corresponds to id number in posts table FROM users table. Then i will use `COUNT(*)` function and `GROUP BY username` statement to be able to get post count for every user.
How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried with a Join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't group by username, because there could be multiple users having the same name. Instead group by the user's id.

```
SELECT users.username, count(*)
  FROM users, posts
  WHERE users.id = posts.user_id
  GROUP BY users.id;
```

Comment: If there are multiple users with the same name, then only including `username` in the resultset will not enable you to distinguish between them.

Comment: yeah, but it is easy to add users.id, users.firstname (if such exists) or similar. The OP only wanted to select usernames, therefore I only included this field.

Comment: username column is unique in my table. So there is no need to discuss that ^^ Thanks :) @eggyal

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher: I know.  I was just continuing with the premise you stated in your answer "*there could be multiple users having the same name*"—if that were the case, your SQL would be problematic.  Certainly adding `id` to the resultset would be a solution, I was just trying to point out the inconsistency.  :)